# Kick off a function when two properties in state are set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React JS and am slowly blundering my way along but hit an issues I figured I'd ask about here.

I have a component that is a container of the state and all the data I care about

```
class PirateContainer extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        PirateCaptains: [],
        Year: [],
        Ship: [],

        PirateChoices: {
            SelectedYear : "",
            SelectedPirateCaptain : "",
            SelectedShip : ""
        }
    };
    this.handleYearChange = this.handleYearChange.bind(this);
    this.handleShipChange = this.handleShipChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePirateCaptainChange = this.handlePirateCaptainChange.bind(this);
}     

popYear(accessLevel){
    fetch('https://Pirateman/api/Years').then(response => {
        return response.json();             
        })
        .then((json) => {                
            this.setState(
                prevState => ({
                Year: json,
                Choices: {
                    ...prevState.PirateChoices,
                    SelectedYear: json[0]
                }
            }), () => {                    
                console.log(this.state);}
            );
        });            
    }



popCaptain({
    fetch('https://Pirateman/api/PirateCaptains').then(response => {
        return response.json();             
        })
        .then((json) => {                
            this.setState(
                prevState => ({
                PirateCaptain: json,
                PirateChoices: {
                    ...prevState.PirateChoices,
                    SelectedPirateCaptain: json[0]
                }
            }), () => {console.log(this.state);}
            );
        });            
    }

popShip(year, captain){            
    fetch('https://Pirateman/api/Ships/' + year + '/' + captain ).then(response => {
        return response.json();             
        })
        .then((json) => {                
            this.setState(
                prevState => ({
                Ship: json,
                PirateChoices: {
                    ...prevState.PirateChoices,
                    SelectedShip: json[0]
                }
            }), () => {console.log(this.state);}
            );
        });            
    }



handleYearChange(e) {
    let value = e.target.value;        
    if(this.state.PirateChoices.SelectedYear === value)
    {
        console.log('Do nothing')
    }
    else
    {
        this.setState(
            prevState => ({
                    PirateChoices: {
                        ...prevState.PirateChoices,
                        SelectedYear: value
                    }
        }), () => {console.log(this.state)}
        );
    }
}

handlePirateCaptainChange(e) {        
    let value = e.target.value;
    if(this.state.PirateChoices.SelectedPirateCaptain === value)
    {
        console.log('Do nothing')
    }
    else
    {
    this.setState(
        prevState => ({
                PirateChoices: {
                    ...prevState.PirateChoices,
                    SelectedPirateCaptain: value
                }
    }), () => {console.log(this.state)}
    );
}
}

handleShipChange(e) {        
    let value = e.target.value;
    if(this.state.PirateChoices.SelectedShip === value)
    {
        console.log('Do nothing')
    }
    else
    {
    this.setState(
        prevState => ({
                PirateChoices: {
                    ...prevState.PirateChoices,
                    SelectedShip: value
                }
    }), () => {console.log(this.state)}
    );
}
}
```

I have a generic component that loads a select form that takes the change function and triggers onchange.

So the first thing the app does is get Years and PirateCaptains from a service and sets the state of those (as well as the Selected Ship and PirateCaptain which is the first entry of the array shown).  On change the selected is updated.

The problem I have is that the Ship data depends on the combination of SelectedPirateCaptain and SelectedYear.

I feel like the easy way of populating that is having it trigger on change of either of those two properties,  but I can't figure out a way to set up a function to do that.

I've also tried (for initial loads) using promises or callbacks but can't seem to figure out how to get it to wait until the state of both selected properties has a value.  (I tried a while loop but the function never seems to get the state with the value.)

Any help is greatly appreciated in advance,  I suspect I'm being an idiot and missing something obvious so thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `componentDidUpdate()` in order to check for the changes in `SelectedPirateCaptain` and `SelectedYear`, and according to those changes update the Ship data: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: That's what I was missing,  thanks!